# How to find a circle’s tangents at points on its circumference?

Tags: vectors, circles, 3d, orthogonality

I have a circle in 3-space (the coordinates of its center, its radius, and a vector normal to its plane). I also have several points on that circle. Now I want to find the unit tangents to the circle at these points directed clockwise with respect to the normal vector.

For this, I need to find every perpendicular vector to my points lying on the circle and eliminate all but one, which is perpendicular in a clockwise manner to the vector that goes through circle center and circumference point.

Can anyone explain how I can do this cause I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by “I **have**” the circle? You know its center and radius? What do you mean by “a 3d circle”? A sphere? A circle in general position in ${\bf R}^3$, so not in the $xy$-plane? What do you mean “the direction” of them? The direction to each of them from the circle’s center? The tangent vector at each of them? What do you mean by *clockwise*? From which direction are you looking at the clock’s face?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I have a 3d circle(center, radius and normal vector). I will edit accordingly

Comment: A circle **in 3-space**?  Your term “3d circle” is nonstandard and ambiguous.

Comment: Yes a circle in 3d space, not a sphere.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that you found “**the** 3d points” that lie (not *lies*) on it?

Comment: HINT: What’s the relationship between any two unit vectors $u$ and $v$ that are perpendicular? How do their respective coordinates, $(x_u, y_u, z_u)$ and $(x_v, y_v, z_v)$, compare?

Comment: the points that creates the circle. The points of the circle.

Comment: What do you mean by “**the** points that creates the circle”? Clearly every circle consists of infinitely many points. And any three of those infinitely many suffice to uniquely determine that circle.

Comment: I found the 3d circle equation and I chose a point in every 10 degree. Considering that a circle is 360 degree, I got 36 points that I want to find tangent vectors for.

Comment: Are you familiar with the cross product of two vectors in ${\bf R}^3$?

Comment: What we’ve discussed so far should give you enough to piece together a solution.  Okay, what we’ve discussed plus maybe the dot product of vectors and the norms of vectors.

Comment: As much as any person that reads such topic on the internet.

Comment: Well I didn't get what you expected me to get.

Comment: What is your goal here? Is it (1) to learn the underlying math or (2) to have somebody hand you a solution? One reason for asking is that achieving number 2 will nearly thwart number 1.

Comment: I need to create this algorithm in short notice. So I care more about the algorithm than learning.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be the circle, ${\bf c}\in {\bf R}^3$ be its center, and $\bf n$ be a normal to the plane containing $C$. For any point $\bf p$ on $C$, the displacement vector from $\bf c$ to $\bf p$ is simply ${\bf d}={\bf p}-{\bf c}$, and so the (unit) outward-pointing vector perpendicular to $C$ at $\bf p$ is ${\bf o} = \frac{1}{||{\bf d|}|} {\bf d}$.

Thus the clockwise-pointing tangent to $C$ at $\bf p$ is then
$$\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf t}&=&\frac{1}{||{\bf n}||}{\bf n}\times{\bf o} \\
&=& \frac{1}{||{\bf n}|| \; ||{\bf p}-{\bf c}||}{\bf n}\times({\bf p}-{\bf c}),
\end{eqnarray}$$
where *clockwise* is defined in terms of observing $C$ along $\bf n$.